# Only allowing a certain user to access a page in Kentico

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I only want to allow a certain user to access a page in Kentico, but as Deny is more powerful than Allow, there doesn't seem to be a way of doing this (e.g. I can't deny Everyone but the user). Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read this : **http://devnet.kentico.com/Forums.aspx?forumid=55&threadid=28799**?? And also : **http://devnet.kentico.com/Downloads/KenticoCMS_Security-facts.pdf**

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the [document permissions](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/6_0/devguide/document_permissions.htm)

according your needs. There are always tons of possible combinations and you have to also think carefully about creating the user roles and assigning users to them. It is good e.g. to draw a schema at first.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a login page and set a session/cookie value if login is successful, then on Page_Load event of the page you want to limit the users, check the value of session/cookie, if user is authenticated, do nothing otherwise redirect the user to login page. I assume that you are familiar with custom page templates.